# Tabularx with different multicolumn spans

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
        *{4}{|m{\dimexpr.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}} |   
    }
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|Y|}{1-3 centered} & 4 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|Y|}{1-2 centered} & \multicolumn{2}{Y|}{3-4 centered} \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Why is the first cell from the second row (multicol 3) NOT centering across the 3 columns, but instead only over 2 colums as the next row does?

Comment: on first sight it seems that behavior of your table is strange ...  but in your code you never define width of `X` column, so it with is select randomly. for better/more correct explanation we should ask author of `tabularx` package.

Comment: try `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|>{\hsize=3\hsize}Y|}{\rule{\hsize}{4pt}} & 4 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=2\hsize}Y|}{\rule{\hsize}{4pt}} & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}Y|}{\rule{\hsize}{4pt}} \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}`. result is what you expected to obtain (discrepancy between rule length and cells width is consequence not considering `\tabcolsep` and \arrayrulewidth`  in determining multi column cells).

Comment: Seems to work, although it feels a bit hacky. Thank you anways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There no need to use `tabularx` only to define a strange `\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering}X}` only used in multicolumns, when you have already defined your columns in order to occupy all the line width: `*{4}{|m{\dimexpr.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}} |`.

A simple `tabular` with `c` multicolumns does the trick.

I have also added a `-1.25\arrayrulewidth` to avoid overfull hbox. The value `1.25\arrayrulewidth` is due to `1\arrayrulewidth` plus `.25\arrayrulewidth`, the latter is `1\arrayrulewidth` (the width of the 5th rule) divided by `4` (the number of columns). *Thanks to Zarko for having pointed out the need of the `.25`.*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{
                *{4}{|m{\dimexpr.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth}} |   
                }
            \hline
            1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{1-3 centered} & 4 \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{1-2 centered} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{3-4 centered} \\ 
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: accurate width of cells is `m{\dimexpr.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.25\arrayrulewidth}` ;-).

Comment: i have great teacher here on site. one of them are you  :-)

Comment: really? then you are extraordinary one ;-)

Comment: @Zarko Thank you! I've seriously used LaTeX for about a year and a half, even if I know about its existence since 2010 (and I was enthusiast about it at once).

Answer (score 0):

less simple as answer of [CarLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101651/carlatex), however it is based on use of `tabularx` (improved version of my comment to your question):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcc[2]{% shortcut for cells spanned two columns
    \multicolumn{2}{#1>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth}C|}{#2}}
\newcommand\mccc[2]{% shortcut for cells spanned three columns
    \multicolumn{3}{#1>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth}C|}{#2}}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
%\setlength\arrayrulewidth{10pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|C|C|C|}
    \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    \hline
\mccc{|}{ \rule{\hsize}{4pt} }                  & 4             \\
    \hline
\mccc{|}{ 1-3 centered }                        & 4             \\
    \hline
\mcc{|}{ \rule{\hsize}{4pt} }   & \mcc{}{ \rule{\hsize}{4pt} }  \\
    \hline
\mcc{|}{ 1-2 centered }         & \mcc{}{ 3-4 centered }        \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]